# Calculating the Riemann Curvature tensor out of sectional curvature

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Hi everybody,

my question is the following: Let $(M^n,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold and $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ be an orthonomal frame in a point. Assume, that we now the sectional curvatures of all planes, spanned by these vectors, i.e. we know the components $R_{ijij}$ of the curvature tensor.

Is it then possible to calculate all other components $R_{ijkl}$?

The problem is, that if I want, e.g. to calculate $R_{ijik}$ by the polarization identity, I need to know the sectional curvature spanned by $e_1,e_j+e_k$ which I assume to be unknown.

Is it then possible to calculate, or at least to estimate the sectional curvature from above by $R_{ijij}$, $R_{jkjk}$ and $R_{ikik}$?

Comment: Maybe I am missing something. But, given any 2-plane you can choose a orthonormal basis of this 2-plane as a linear combination of the vectors you are giving, and since everything is linear you can thus express the sectional curvature of this 2-plane as a combination of the data you know. But then, you know the full sectional curvature and this determines the Riemann curvature tensor... Where am I wrong? 

Comment: diverietti, I think the question assumes an initial choice of an orthonormal frame and that you know only the sectional curvatures of 2-planes spanned by pairs of vectors from the plane. The question is whether given this limited amount of information (a frame and the corresponding $n(n-1)/2$ sectional curvatures), you can compute or estimate the sectional curvature of an arbitrary 2-plane.

Comment: The sectional curvatures determine the Ricci tensor. 

Comment: No it does'nt, by the same argument as above. You have given $n(n-1)/2$ sectional curvatures but the Ricci tensor has $n(n+1)/2$ different components.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not if $n > 2$. The full Riemann tensor has $n^2(n^2-1)/12$ different components. The number of sectional curvatures spanned by two basis vectors is $n(n-1)/2$. The former is always larger than the latter if $n > 2$.

As for estimating the sectional curvature, you might want to study the case $n = 3$ first, because everything reduces to studying a $3$-by-$3$ symmetric matrix. There, your question reduces to the question of whether you can estimate the eigenvalues of such a matrix from knowing its diagonal components.

Comment: Wait a minute Deane, this does not prove anything.  Any bilinear form has more parameters than the corresponding quadratic form.  Nonetheless, the polarisation formula allows one to go from the quadratic form to the bilinear form.

Comment: @MikhailKatz, doesn’t the polarization formula require knowing values of the quadratic form for vectors (here, pairs of vectors) other than the values for only basis vectors?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question.  Arch Stanton answered the question I had in mind.

Answer (score 8):

There is an explicit, but complicated, formula for going from the sectional curvature back to the curvature tensor in equation (1.10) on page 16 of Cheeger and Ebin's book.

Comment: Thanks! I needed this reference badly.